# use dispInterface in Delphi with no classid

Tags: delphi, com

I've imported a type library into Delphi XE2 that has many dispinterfaces. Most of them have had an autocreated coclass and corresponding delphi T interface automatically created.

However, some of the dispinterfaces that I need to work with have no classid; I've tried every example that I could find on the net to utilize the dispinterface(s) in question. Here's what the interface looks like:

```pascal
DIID_ITableListener: TGUID = '{83D42EA5-2C18-46EB-823B-262D62DF8CF1}';
... 
ITableListener = dispinterface;
...
// *********************************************************************//
// DispIntf:  ITableListener
// Flags:     (4096) Dispatchable
// GUID:      {83D42EA5-2C18-46EB-823B-262D62DF8CF1}
// *********************************************************************//
ITableListener = dispinterface
  ['{83D42EA5-2C18-46EB-823B-262D62DF8CF1}']
  procedure Added(const rowID: WideString; const rowDataObj: IRow); dispid 1610743809;
  procedure Changed(const rowID: WideString; const rowDataObj: IRow); dispid 1610743810;
  procedure Deleted(const rowID: WideString; const rowDataObj: IRow); dispid 1610743811;
  procedure StatusChanged(status: TableStatus); dispid 1610743812;
end;
```

Here's an example from another interface in the type library wrapper that uses this dispinterface:

```
procedure subscribeUpdate(updateType: TableUpdateType; const listenerObj: ITableListener);
```

Here's a VB.NET example that is provided that explains how the dispinterface is supposed to be used:

```vb
' If you want to use methods of the ITableListener interface, you must create a 
' class that+ implements the interface. For example,

public class TableListener implements ITableListener { }

' In your application you must create an instance of the class that implements  
' the interface. For example,

TableListener tableListener = new TableListener();
```

With no ClassID how do I implement this in Delphi? How do I do an instantiation? I thought it would have something to do with implementing an IDispatch interface descendant, but again without a ClassID I couldn't find a way to make this work.

Help!

Thanks.

Comment: You're supposed to implement this interface, so you can use whatever ClassID you feel like.

Comment: To elaborate on Eric's comment, `ITableListener` is an event sink interface, as evident by the fact that it is declared as a `DIID`. You are supposed to write a class in your own code that implements that interface (you do not need a ClassID for that) and then instantiate that class and pass it to another COM object via its `subscribeUpdate()` method. That allows the COM object to then use your `ITableListener` to send events to you when it needed to.

Comment: Thanks Eric and Remy for the replies. I did create a class, but I couldn't figure out with the examples that I was able to find both in help and online how to do this and have it work.
I did create a class as a descendant of TObject, I believe I also tried descending from TInterfacedObject as well. However the interface calls specifically require a parameter of type ITableListener. When I tried passing my class it would not accept it as it was of the wrong type.

Comment: Just an FYI, this is a .NET backend; I don't know how that affects the details but thought I should point it out.

Does anyone have an example? I've tried many different things and dumped about 8 hours into this to no avail...

Thanks.

Comment: So far nothing works, out of all of the examples that I have been able to find. The bottom line is, the parameter that is passed requires the dispinterface type; it will not take any other type. So again I ask, how do you implement/instantiate a dispinterface in delphi? Examples, please.

Comment: You need to implement an IDispatch (with arbitrary ClassID) that has implementations for the dispids named in ITableListener.  (I.e., your implementation of IDispatch::Invoke needs to support dispids 1610743809, 1610743810, 1610743811, etc., and IDispatch::GetIdsOfNames needs to map "Added" to dispid 1610743809, etc.).  [This article](http://delphi-kb.blogspot.com/2010/12/what-is-dispinterface.html) appears to have some notes on how to implement dispinterfaces in Delphi.

Comment: Thanks Eric. The problem with the example that you gave is that my CLassID that I created for this is not registered so when I try to do this:      
  disp := CreateComObject(CLASS_TableListener) as IDispatch;         I get a EOleSysError 'Class not registered error'. How do I register my custom classid?                                                   Here is my classid declaration:                                        
const
  CLASS_TableListener: TGUID = '{03F5A8BD-7193-4B58-8352-C86E9E1F1213}';

Comment: @EricBrown - You state that I need to implement methods in an IDispatch, but an interface has no implementation so I how am I supposed to implement anything with an IDispatch? None of the MANY examples I have gone through illustrate implementing dispinterface methods via an IDispatch. Rather they show in one form or another a class that implements the methods. But I've tried that; a class that implements an interface that has methods with matching disipids to the dispinterface in question can't be passed as a param to any of these methods! I'm going in circles, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I mean that your Delphi class needs to implement the methods for IDispatch (Invoke, GetIdsOfNames, etc.).  Since you haven't posted code that follows the protocol in the [previous link](http://delphi-kb.blogspot.com/2010/12/what-is-dispinterface.html), I can't tell what you might have been doing wrong.

Comment: @EricBrown - Fair enough. I'll try to post some code tonight.

Answer (score 1):

So I went through the sample provided in [the link](http://delphi-kb.blogspot.com/2010/12/what-is-dispinterface.html), and substituted your interfaces for the interfaces in the link, and came up with this:

```
ITableListener = dispinterface
  ['{83D42EA5-2C18-46EB-823B-262D62DF8CF1}']
  procedure Added(const rowID: WideString; const rowDataObj: IRow); dispid 1610743809;
  procedure Changed(const rowID: WideString; const rowDataObj: IRow); dispid 1610743810;
  procedure Deleted(const rowID: WideString; const rowDataObj: IRow); dispid 1610743811;
  procedure StatusChanged(status: TableStatus); dispid 1610743812;
end;

IMyTableListener = interface(IDispatch)
  ['{INSERT ARBITRARY GUID HERE}']
  procedure Added(const rowID: WideString; const rowDataObj: IRow); 
  procedure Changed(const rowID: WideString; const rowDataObj: IRow); 
  procedure Deleted(const rowID: WideString; const rowDataObj: IRow);
  procedure StatusChanged(status: TableStatus);
end;


TMyTableListener = class (TAutoObject, IMyTableListener)
public
  procedure Added(const rowID: WideString; const rowDataObj: IRow); 
  procedure Changed(const rowID: WideString; const rowDataObj: IRow); 
  procedure Deleted(const rowID: WideString; const rowDataObj: IRow);
  procedure StatusChanged(status: TableStatus);
end;

{ ... }
var
Disp: IDispatch;
Dispint: ITableListener;
{ ... }
// this may require that TMyTableListener is registered...
Disp := CreateComObject(TMyTableListener) as IDispatch;
// alternatively, try this (not sure about syntax):
Disp := new TMyTableListener as IDispatch;
Disp.AddRef();   // in C++, at least, creating the class via new() results in a 0 refcount, so you need to AddRef() so that releasing the object destroys the object appropriately...
Dispint := ITableListener(Disp);
subscribeUpdate(updateType, Dispint);
{ ... }
```

Comment: You beat me to it, thank you for this. I've implemented this. Your first suggestion for the construction won't work because CreateComObject takes a TGUID as a parameter, not an interfaced class. When I try to use the second construction method I get the error 'Object factory for class TFXTableListener missing'.

Comment: This gives me a 'The parameter is incorrect' error: code var disp: IDispatch; DispInt: ITableListener; TypLib: ITypeLib; begin CoInitializeEx(Nil,0); OleCheck(LoadRegTypeLib(LIBID_mytypelib_com,1,3,0,TypLib)); disp := TFXTableListener.Create(TypLib,DIID_ITableListener) as IDispatch; disp._AddRef; DispInt := ITableListener(Disp); subscribeUpdate(TableUpdateType_Update,DispInt);

Comment: In the above, TFXTableListener has a declaration as follows: `code

  TFXTableListener = class(TAutoIntfObject, IFXTableListener)
  public
    procedure Added(const rowID: WideString; const rowDataObj: IRow);
    procedure Changed(const rowID: WideString; const rowDataObj: IRow);
    procedure Deleted(const rowID: WideString; const rowDataObj: IRow);
    procedure StatusChanged(status: TableStatus);
  end;`

Comment: I'm not a Delphi guru, just a COM guru.  As far as I can tell, you've implemented the dispinterface, and it should work.  Can you verify that you can call `DispInt.StatusChanged(TableUpdateType_Update)` without error?  If you can, you've implemented the dispinterface.  At this point, I'd strongly suggest picking up a 90-day trial of [VS Pro](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx) and seeing if it actually works in VB

Comment: It doesn't work Eric. I get an access violation if I try to run DispInt.StatusChanged(TableStatus_Initial), since it is an event, not a method that I can call (I guess). The DispInt is instantiated, so at this point I don't know what parameter could be wrong. Thanks.

Comment: if you're getting an AV calling through the dispinterface, then I'd track down why that's failing.  Run it under the debugger and solve that first.

Comment: Here are the last entries from the call stack when she blows: `code 0048a746 +07a MyApp.exe System.Win.ComObj           DispatchInvokeError
0048a3f1 +155 MyApp.exe System.Win.ComObj           DispatchInvoke
0048a7c9 +02d MyApp.exe System.Win.ComObj           DispCallByID
0060a611 +041 MyApp.exe mytypelib_com_TLB    4932  +1 TTable.subscribeUpdate`     Looks like the internal invoke is failing. Doesn't that indicate that I need to do something more in the definition? I haven't implemented GetIdsByName nor Invoke... with this object type (TAutoIntfObject) I don't think you need to implement that

Comment: Can you call the function through `TFXTableListener` directly (without using IDispatch)?  Start at the bottom & work up from there.

Comment: I'll try that. I stepped into Delphi's underlying source; it fails on DispatchInvoke. I added dispid's to the IFXTableListener. When I step through, I find that the internal Delphi code is getting the correct dispid number... I'll try your suggestion. However it is failing on StatusChanged. Thanks. ***UPDATE*** When I instantiate the class as a class instead of as an IDispatch, all methods execute as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved. Please see [Troubleshooting COM error "The parameter is incorrect"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693588/troubleshooting-com-error-the-parameter-is-incorrect).

Many thanks to @EricBrown and @RemyLebeau for their assistance.