# Troubleshooting COM error "The parameter is incorrect"

Tags: .net, delphi, com

Environment is Delphi XE2 Enterprise.

Relates to [use dispInterface in Delphi with no classid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564282/use-dispinterface-in-delphi-with-no-classid). Re-posting as a different question as I have moved well beyond the previous issues (thanks to @EricBrown) and now have a more specific problem.

I've got a .NET dll with a COM interface that I've registered on the computer and have imported as a type library into Delphi. I'm using the tlb.pas file that Delphi created.

Working with a couple of dispInterfaces that I've implemented in IDispatch interfaces and TAutoIntf descendant classes, I've successfully initialized the classes and interfaces that I need to call methods in the COM interface to the .NET library. Here is some code to illustrate the declaration/implementation:

```
// COM Event Sink GUID
DIID_IResponseListener: TGUID = '{ABC29F08-B628-4747-BA9E-469D408E57B9}';

// *********************************************************************//
// DispIntf:  IResponseListener
// Flags:     (4096) Dispatchable
// GUID:      {ABC29F08-B628-4747-BA9E-469D408E57B9}
// *********************************************************************//
  IResponseListener = dispinterface
    ['{ABC29F08-B628-4747-BA9E-469D408E57B9}']
    procedure RequestCompleted(const requestID: WideString; const responseObj: IResponse); dispid 1610744833;
    procedure RequestFailed(const requestID: WideString; const error: WideString); dispid 1610744834;
    procedure TablesUpdates(const responseObj: IResponse); dispid 1610744835;
 end;

...my implementation:
  IFXResponseListener = interface(IDispatch)
['{3204D3F7-5DF2-4470-89D5-D34F4F6F0381}']
    procedure RequestCompleted(const requestID: WideString; const responseObj: IResponse); dispid 1610744833; safecall;
    procedure RequestFailed(const requestID: WideString; const error: WideString); dispid 1610744834; safecall;
    procedure TablesUpdates(const responseObj: IResponse); dispid 1610744835; safecall;
  end;

  TFXResponseListener = class(TAutoIntfObject,IFXResponseListener)
  private
    FDisp: IDispatch;
    FResp: IResponse;
    function GetResponseListIntf: IResponseListener;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy;
  published
    procedure RequestCompleted(const requestID: WideString; const responseObj: IResponse); safecall;
    procedure RequestFailed(const requestID: WideString; const error: WideString); safecall;
    procedure TablesUpdates(const responseObj: IResponse); safecall;
    property ResponseObj: IResponse read FResp;
    property ListenerDispIntf: IResponseListener read GetResponseListIntf;
  end;

...

{ TFXResponseListener }


constructor TFXResponseListener.Create;
var
  TypeLib: ITypeLib;
begin
  OleCheck(LoadRegTypeLib(LIBID_fxcore2_com,fxcore2_comMajorVersion,fxcore2_comMinorVersion,0,TypeLib));
  inherited Create(TypeLib,DIID_IResponseListener);
end;

destructor TFXResponseListener.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

function TFXResponseListener.GetResponseListIntf: IResponseListener;
begin
  FDisp := Self as IFXResponseListener;
  FDisp._AddRef;
  Result := IResponseListener(FDisp);
end;

procedure TFXResponseListener.RequestCompleted(const requestID: WideString; const responseObj: IResponse);
begin
  showmessage('Completed: ' + requestID);
  FResp := responseObj;
end;

procedure TFXResponseListener.RequestFailed(const requestID: WideString; const error: WideString);
begin
  showmessage('Failed: ' + requestID);
end;

procedure TFXResponseListener.TablesUpdates(const responseObj: IResponse);
begin
  showmessage('TablesUpdates');
end;
```

Here is where I attempt to use the interface:

```
FRespList := TFXResponseListener.Create;
  try
    FSess.subscribeResponse(FRespList.ListenerDispIntf);
  except
    // errors out here with 'The parameter is incorrect'
  end;
```

Tracing this down into the bowels of System.Win.ComObj, at line 1793 it calls:

```
Status := Dispatch.Invoke(DispID, GUID_NULL, 0, InvKind, DispParams, Result, @ExcepInfo, nil);
```

At this point, the DispID parameter is valid (1610743816), GUID_NULL is '(0, 0, 0, (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))', InvKind is '1', DispParams is '($2152FE8, nil, 1, 0)', Result is '$12FE24', @ExcepInfo is '$12FDE0'.

In System.pas, line 30133, TInterfacedObject.QueryInterface is called twice. On the second run it returns the result 'E_NOINTERFACE', and the dreaded 'The parameter is incorrect' message appears.

I'm really not sure where to go from here, but I'm hoping a COM expert and/or Delphi expert  can review this and see something amiss.

I'm also wondering if there is a .NET framework version or other issue. I'm using framework version 4.5.1; not sure how to determine if the .NET assembly is kosher with this version of the framework or if it really needs an earlier version.

Any relevant .NET/COM debugging techniques would be greatly appreciated.

Also please note, I can duplicate this issue with a different dispinterface/IDispatch/TAutoIntfObj descendant class and similar call, identical to a 'T'.

Thanks.

Comment: What is `FRespList` declared as? `FSess.subscribeResponse()`?  What guid is `QueryInterface()` being asked for when it returns `E_NOINTERFACE`? Is that guid a standard guid or defined in the type library? Also, the implementation of `TFXResponseListener.GetResponseListIntf()` looks dangerously suspicious to me, did you create that or did Delphi auto-generate it?

Comment: FRespList is declared as a TFXResponseListener. FSess is an ISession interface from the type library. The Session subscribeResponse procedure takes one param, an IResponseListener which is defined as a dispInterface. TFXResponseListener.GetResponseListIntf is something that I defined, as is all of the TFXResponseListener class & IFXResponseListener interface. QueryInterface is testing this: (3288121758, 43376, 4562, (139, 90, 0, 160, 201, 183, 201, 196))`, I don't know how to translate that to a GUID.

Comment: What's wierd is that it hits TInterfacedObject.QueryInterface twice. The first time it's called the IID is `(0, 0, 0, (192, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 70)). The second call is the interface listed above. In tracing through, it's the call to subscribeResponse(IResponseListener) that results in the 2 calls to QueryInterface. On the first call it returns a result of -0- (success?)

Comment: The producer of the COM interface puts it this way: "Could you please try to bind to the COM events by analogy..." and "You could try to implement the method in Delphi by analogy with the method session_RequestCompleted...". The producer of the library doesn't know Delphi nor has any staff that knows Delphi. Since I'm not that good with .NET or COM, it makes troubleshooting this issue difficult.

Comment: `FRespList` should be changed to `IFXResponseListener`, and get rid of the `ListenerDispIntf` property completely: `FSess.subscribeResponse(FRespList);` As for `QueryInterface()`, the first guid is `IID_IUnknown`, which all COM interfaces must implement (`TInterfacedObject` handles that for you). The second guid is [`IID_IManagedObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404390(v=vs.110).aspx). So it would appear that `subscribeResponse()` is expecting a .NET object for the listener and thus will not work with a Delphi COM object.

Comment: Perhaps I should try to use their C++ interface. Never written an interface to a C++ library, and I'm not sure that it is unmanaged... I did look at the documentation for the C++ api and it is using interfaces a lot; would that be a problem for implementing a C++ interface? I can provide examples and even the .chm documentation file.

Comment: If the C++ interface is COM-based then it will work fine as Delphi COM is compatible with C++ COM (after all, that is what COM is all about - binary compatibility across languages/platforms). Sounds like the .NET interface is not actually using COM correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this one is in the bag. Thanks to @EricBrown and @RemyLebeau, I was able to get this to work.

Remy's suggestion of changing the instantiation of FRespList from:

```
var
  FRespList: TFXResponseListener;
```

to:

```
var 
  FRespList: IFXResponseListener;
```

...did the trick. So when I instantiate using

```
FRespList := TFXResponseListener.Create;
```

...I get the right result, and everything is fat, dumb and happy.

Also I need to point out that the GUID that is assigned to the dispinterface has to be used for the IDispatch interface descendant that I created, otherwise, we're back to 'The parameter is incorrect.'. Wonder if that's documented somewhere...

Also kind of weird, when I'm done with my IDispatch descendant I nil it. That reduces the refcount on the TAutoIntfObject descendant to *2*. Which results in a memory leak. I tested and tried different things to get this refcount to dec, finally had to do some weirdness:

```
**procedure** TMyClass.Destroy; // <- changed from **destructor** TMyClass.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy; // <- had to call this first!
  // then...
  while Self.RefCount > 0 do
    IUnknown(Self)._Release;
end;
```

...and then call MyClassInstance.Destroy; to get the class to free without AV's nor mem leaks.

If anyone knows why I had 3 references to my class, why FreeAndNil(MyClassInstance) and IMyClass := Nil; leaves a refcount of 2 with an Access Violation and/or a memory leak, why I had to destroy the inherited first, why I had to typecast the class as an IUnknown and manually release the instances, please speak up.

On another interface/class pair I still get a mem leak from TServerEventDispatch. This is one of the classes that Delphi auto-created in the tlb.pas file. If anyone has a suggestion...

COM... ya' gotta love it!

I'd like to give any points to both Eric Brown and Remy Lebeau, but I don't know how.

So... THANKS GUYS!